# Действительно ли нужна запятая перед "так"?

Tags: запятые

Отлично, на желание, так на желание.

Comment: ***Не нужна.***

Comment: А может и не после? И не запятая?

Comment: Значит "на желание так на желание" не требует запятых?

Comment: Людиии, помогите...

Comment: Да, не требует. Не заметил, что у вас было "после", имел в виду не надо перед.

Comment: А почему, кстати, у вас фамилия или псевдоним пишется с большим количеством букв, чем одноимённая страна, если не секрет? Уже давно заметил.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ) а псевдоним такой уже давно, и он не копирует название страны

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая не нужна.

Розенталь:
Запятая не ставится при повторении слова с частицей *так* для усиления смысла:
*Пропаду так пропаду, всё равно!

Свадьба так свадьба; я — Огудалова, я нищенства не допущу.

Вот это была косьба так косьба!

Да так да, нет так нет.

Не надо так не надо.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105